# JSON Как правильнее структурировать формат запроса

Tags: json, spring, rest

Пишу `REST` приложение на `Spring Boot` с использованием `Spring MVC`.

При написании контроллера встал вопрос как правильно распределить данные, приходящие с запросом от пользователя: какие из них передавать с параметрами запроса (`@RequestParam`), какие через переменную пути (`@PathVariable`), а какие передавать в виде пар ключ-значение в самом теле `JSON`'а (`@RequestBody`)?

Если подробнее, то уже есть метод, который возвращает коллекцию объектов сущностей. Он доступен по адресу `http://localhost:8080/rest/tasks` с ключом `'page'` в самом теле `JSON`'a.

Сейчас пишу метод, который по запросу должен возвращать один из объектов сущности (сущность `Task`), где пользователь должен передать каким-то способом `id` объекта и номер страницы (у каждого объекта `Task` есть список объектов `Comment`, которые разбиты на страницы).

Так вот вопрос: каким образом ЛУЧШЕ указать `id`, номер страницы (`page`) и вообще указание на то, что это запрос на получение одного объекта?

То есть например, если я хочу получить страницу под номером 3 объекта `Task` с `id` == 17 скажем, то лучше сделать такой формат запроса:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/tasks
```

```
{
    "id" : 17
    "page" : 3
    
}
```

или например такой:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/tasks/view/17?page=3
```

```
{
    
}
```

? Или вообще какой? То есть так называемые лучшие практики хотелось бы узнать.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, разницы особой нету. Я бы сделал с помощью второго способа

Только прикола не понял.
Это первая ссылка, ты там ещё jaon какой-то передал
http://localhost:8080/rest/tasks

Потом сделал  вторую ссылку, она отлична от первой, если я правильно понимаю проблему, то можно передать два аргумента в ссылке сразу

http://localhost:8080/rest/tasks?id=17&page=3

Это делается с помощью знака &